# Count pairs occurence and plot them

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot-table

I have this dataset called x for example:

| client_id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I then want to create another table, that calculates the number of occurence of each possible pair in the table. So the result would be something like this:

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 0 |
| c | 1 |
| a,b | 0 |
| a,c | 0 |
| b,c | 1 |
| a,b,c | 1 |

That means for example that for the first row, a occured (was equal to 1) alone (means other columns didn't, and so they were at 0) only once.

After this, I want the best way to visualize the result of the pairs in ggplot.

Edit: More explanation of the second table:

a (single letter): a is the strictly one which occured (rest are 0).
a,b (two letters): a and b both occured, but not the rest.
a,b,c (three letters): all a,b,c occured at the same time (all are set to 1).

Comment: Could you explain this in details? I see `b` has a 1 in rows 2 and 4. So why is `b` 0? etc, why is `a,c` 0 yet `a,b,c` 1?

Comment: why is `c` 0? row 3 has a single `c`

Comment: b, means when b occured all by itself alone. For row 2, it's the combination b,c, because both occured at the same time. For row 4, it's combination a,b,c, because all these three columns occured. 

a (single letter)= a is the strictly one which occured.
a,b (two letters)= a and b both occured, but not the rest.
a,b,c (three letters)= all a,b,c occured at the same time.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for highlighting this one, I made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the pivoting part, not sure of the best way (atm) to plot.

```r
library(dplyr)
poss <- data.frame(pair=unlist(sapply(seq_along(names(quux)[-1]), function(z) combn(x = names(quux)[-1], z, FUN = function(y) paste(y, collapse=",")))))
poss
#    pair
# 1     a
# 2     b
# 3     c
# 4   a,b
# 5   a,c
# 6   b,c
# 7 a,b,c


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
quux %>%
  pivot_longer(-client_id) %>%
  summarize(pair = paste(sort(unique(name[value==1])), collapse = ","), .by = client_id) %>%
  count(pair) %>%
  full_join(poss, by="pair") %>%
  mutate(n = coalesce(n, 0)) %>%
  arrange(nchar(pair), pair)
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   pair      n
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         1
# 2 b         0
# 3 c         1
# 4 a,b       0
# 5 a,c       0
# 6 b,c       1
# 7 a,b,c     1
```

Data

---

```r
quux <- structure(list(client_id = 1:4, a = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), b = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), c = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I tried the above code on my machine and it's giving me a count of 0 for all pairs except a,b,c pair which has 12. Is this happening only with me?

Comment: after some trial, the below code worked for me:
quux %>%
    pivot_longer(-client_id) %>%
    group_by(client_id)%>%
    summarize(pair = paste(sort(unique(name[value==1])), collapse = ","), )%>%
    count(pair)%>%
    full_join(poss, by="pair") %>%
    mutate(n = coalesce(n, 0)) %>%
    arrange(nchar(pair), pair)

I just added a group_by before summarise, and removed the .by inside summarise.

Thanks for this

Comment: the `.by=` argument requires dplyr_1.1 or newer; your use of `group_by(.)` works fine with older versions too, glad you found it